# как загрузить на github release артефакт сборки?

Tags: c++, github, travis-ci

С тревиса хочу загрузить артефакт в github release:

```
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: $GITHUB_API_KEY
  file_glob: true
  file:
    - "${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/bin/artefact.jar"
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    tags: true
    all_branches: true
```

Но deploy пропускает -

> 1mSkipping a deployment with the releases provider because this is not
> a tagged commit

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Из комита, но котором сборка выдает сообщение, есть созданный релиз или хотя бы тег? Ведь сообщение об ошибке говорит именно об этом

Comment: @Roman Konoval использую:
before_deploy:
      # Set up git user name and tag this commit
      - git config --local user.name "user"
      - git config --local user.email "email"
      - export TRAVIS_TAG=${TRAVIS_TAG:-$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')-$(git log --format=%h -1)}
      - git tag $TRAVIS_TAG

или что-то другое имеете ввиду?